# type=number formatting, jquery validate

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, jquery-validate

I have gotten a requirement where the customer wants numbers to be seperated with space by the thousands. Ex: 1000000 becomes 1 000 000.

My application is built with .NET MVC5 and I am using jquery validate for the front end validation.

I tried to just format the inputs as the user types, but the validation wouldn't work. For example it interprated "8 000" as "8".

I then tried to change all type=number inputs to type=text, but the numeric validation from jquery validate stopped working, also obviously the html5 features of input=number with min/max validation etc.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this? I can imagine a solution with hidden fields containing the actual data, and other fields just displaying the formatted data, but I feel this is hacky, hard to maintain and not very reliable.

Comment: could you tell me what is the the size of input box.e.g. user could enter `n` no of digits because if there is limit on input box we can do this using split method in JQuery.

Comment: the jquery validation docs mention [jQuery.validator.addMethod](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod) to add custom validation logic. this section also refers to a bundled `pattern` validator using regular expressions (which would be `[1-9][0-9]{0,2}( [0-9]{3})*` in your case; note the space immediately after the left paren), though it isn't listed as a standard validation method.